# How to loop for each record in One2Many field in form view to create dynamic elements?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have a customized One2Many field that contains several records for this current data.

I am working on a form view.

I need to construct something like this: **(I don't want a tree)**

```
<for every record in one2many_field>
  <button something...>
</for>
```

I only want the result as to create 1 button per record in the `one2many_field` and be able to get the data in some fields from the model of the `one2many_field` too.

Is there any way to achieve it? I have searched for some time but found nothing even remotely close to this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve that in a Form View. Views in Odoo are kind of strict but it's mostly to avoid bad stuff to happen.

Anyway, you could think about re-creating the full view by yourself using QWeb View (doc for v14 [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/views.html#qweb))

If you want to keep your Form View, you'll have to use a tree inside the form.
Know that you can totally add buttons in Tree views like adding on a `sale.order.line` something like `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="object" name="product_id_change" string="Force Product Id Change"/>` (useless, just for the example)

[Check example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwxGz.png)

And play with some attrs to change the visibility of fields...

Hope it helped :)